# want to add multiple videoview in single page

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

So,basically I want to add multiple videos in single page .I tried adding it still its not working.there is some bug.Bcoz when I run the app there is no error.I tried experimenting with the code still its not working.I have attached my bvideos.xml and also corresponding java file.

this is my bvideos.java file

```
public class bvideos extends AppCompatActivity {

    private VideoView videoView;
    private MediaController mediaController;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bvideos);

       /* VideoView videoView  = findViewById(R.id.video_view1);
        videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bvideo1);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);*/



        Button photo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bphoto);
        photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent y = new Intent(bvideos.this, mainpage.class);
                startActivity(y);

            }
        });


        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view1);

        /*String fullScreen =  getIntent().getStringExtra("fullScreenInd");
        if("y".equals(fullScreen)){
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }*/

        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bvideo1);

        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

        mediaController = new FullScreenMediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.start();



        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view2);

        /*String fullScreen =  getIntent().getStringExtra("fullScreenInd");
        if("y".equals(fullScreen)){
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }*/

        Uri videoUri1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bvideo2);

        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri1);

        mediaController = new FullScreenMediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.start();





    }
}
```

this is my bvideos.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".bvideos">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/Pink"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView"
                android:layout_width="950dp"
                android:layout_height="550dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:background="@color/purple_200"
                android:text="     BEGINNERS CALLIGRAPHY"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bphoto"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="210dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:text="PHOTOS"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_700"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:text="VIDEOS"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_700"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/video_view1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="242dp" />


        </FrameLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="374dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Brush Calligraphy Alphabets for Beginners| Basic Strokes| Lowercase Alphabets "
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/video_view2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="232dp" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="374dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="How to Gothic Calligraphy Capital and Small Letters From A to Z |Blackletters Calligraphy "
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/video_view3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="232dp" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the start(); call.
Try to add

```
videoView.start();
```

After

```
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
```

Comment: Can u make changes in my code so thats its more clear

Comment: You have three VideoViews, right now you play the next video when you tap on the next button on the MediaController, but at the start the Media Controller is not visible since you have no video playing. I'm not sure how your logic should be, but try to move the playing of the first video outside 
mc.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() { // code } )

Comment: This is how playing a video should look like:
                        String videoPath1 = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bvideo2;
                Uri uri1 = Uri.parse(videoPath1);
                videoView1.setMediaController(mc);
                videoView1.setVideoURI(uri1);
                videoView1.start();

Comment: Try placing the code outside setPrevNextListeners and see if that will work to start with

Comment: I tried still ...only one video is playing other is not working

Comment: I have added the latest code ....please have a look

Comment: You are overriding the         videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view2);
please use videoViewTwo for this one